# "Model dialog is present unhandled exception" even after accepting alert

Tags: javascript, selenium

Hi I've gone through the similar issue posted across the web including stackoverflow unfortunately most of them do not fit my scenario.

In my application (Browser:-IE,Selenium 2.53) I need to click on edit(+icon) in the main page and after which a small popup window would be asking for credential details (i.e Name)then I need to click on ADD/Update icon to conclude the edits.

As shown in the image It should only throw the alert dialg box if we did not enter **URN**. Here in the image below as you can see even after entering the mandatory details it is still throwing the alert Dialog  after clicking **ADD/Update**  .

[image: Issue]

I would appreciate if you guys kindly share your inputs.

Comment: Can you consider updating your Selenium version to 3.4.x along with required drivers please? Thanks

Comment: Hi DebanjanB my entire team is following the old version as such I don't have any say on this.